# `google-chrome` freezes upon launching - DBus.Error

Tags: 12.04, google-chrome

While trying to launch google-chrome from terminal, it launches successfully but shows the following:

```
emre@emre:~$ google-chrome
[9258:9283:0205/003113:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(608)] Failed to get name owner. Got org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Could not get owner of name 'org.chromium.Mtpd': no such name
[9258:9283:0205/003113:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(608)] Failed to get name owner. Got org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Could not get owner of name 'org.chromium.Mtpd': no such name
[9258:9258:0205/003113:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(513)] Failed to call method: org.chromium.Mtpd.EnumerateStorage: object_path= /org/chromium/Mtpd: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.chromium.Mtpd was not provided by any .service files
```

Plus, Google Chrome is not listed as installed in software center in any way. Why is this so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are the kinds of errors you shouldn't worry about - usually it means it's trying to access things that your system wasn't designed for/doesn't include.
Also, Google Chrome by itself is not searchable in the Ubuntu Software Center. Try searching for "google-chrome" instead.

---

Edit:
As a general note, the longer and more specific your search term is, the smaller your chance of finding something unless you're sure of what you're searching for.

In this specific case, if you just typed `google` *or* `chrome`, the Software Center would have shown you `google-chrome`.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem too on both `chromium-browser` and `google-chrome` on `Ubuntu 12.10`

```
alvas@ubi:~$ chromium-browser 
[5404:5425:0331/213025:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(624)] Failed to get name owner. 
Got org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Could not get owner of name
'org.chromium.Mtpd': no such name
```

Then i tried the simple fix found on https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1249837 and the problem was resolved.

(WARNING!  The following command is a last resort and will result in loss of your chrome profile, history, bookmarks, passwords etc.  Make a backup, use with caution):

```
$ sudo rm -rf ~/.config/chromium
```

It seemed like there was some configuration error when Chromium didn't shut down properly.

On the other problem of Google Chrome not found in Ubuntu's software centre, follow this guide http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/10/heres-how-to-install-google-chrome-in-ubuntu-12-10-quantal-quetzal/:

```
# For single core systems.
$ wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb
# For dual core systems.
$ wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i google-chrome*
$ sudo apt-get install -f
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problems, but with CHROMIUM (Google Chrome worked..)
   ERROR:object_proxy.cc(608)] Failed to get name owner. Got org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Could not get owner of name 'org.chromium.Mtpd': no such name

But before they occured, I had a problem at  apt-get install upgrade.
4 packages were "kept back".. (kept back linux-headers-generic-pae )

**How I solved the problem**

1. I removed chromium-browser
2. made than an `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` (this installed the 4 kept back packages)
3. I installed chromium-browser again

(and maybe it was not necessary to remove and install chromium again, maybe it was enough to just make the apt-get disp-upgrade)